# exclusion crawl rule

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, crawl-rules

I have a wiki consisting of an url like this: https://mycompany/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=pagename?action=edit
I'm trying to exclude all the actions, so I created an exclusion: https://mycompany/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=*?action=*
I mark it as an exclusion and to use regular expressions.

Sadly this doesn't work. When I test my url, it will say no rules match this url. I have tried different variations, but none of them give the desired result. even setting https://mycompany/wiki/* as an exclusion rule; will never match any page that is deeper.
I seem to be missing something blatanly obvious.

[image: concerned crawlrule]

[image: all rules]

Answer (score 0):

Whether you set other crawl rules?

You can provide screenshots of crawl rule.

After a full crawl, go to crawl log, in the URL view, check whether wiki URLs in the crawl logs.

Please try this URL "https://mycompany/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=pagename?action=*"

Comment: added a picture of rule + started a full crawl

Comment: Whether the URL you provided is completed? Please try the URL updated in answer.